# How to rectify the socket programming error of reading data from the client?

Tags: c, sockets

The following *c socket programming code* looping all the time without waiting to get data from the file descriptor. This is the part of a server side socket programming. It is not waiting to accept request from client. Please help.

code:

```
while(1){  
  bzero(buffer,256);
  read(newsockfd,buffer,256);  
  printf("%s",buffer);  
  if(n<0){
    printf("reading client message failed\n");    
    return 0;
  }  
  printf("success\n");  

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: `bzero` is deprecated, use `memset` instead

Comment: Look at the output server code is not waiting for the client data to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the return value of `read()` to your `n` variable, but you are expecting `n` to somehow know when `read()` fails.  Fix that assignment, then also fix your loop logic to output only the bytes that were actually read, eg:

```
while(1){  
  memset(buffer,0,256);
  printf("sssssssss\n");  
  n = read(newsockfd,buffer,256);
  if(n<0){
    // if your sockeet is non-blocking then uncomment this code...
    /*
    if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)){
        fd_set rfd;
        FD_ZERO(&rfd);
        FD_SET(newsockfd, &rfd);

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        if (select(newsockfd+1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0){
            continue;
        }
    }
    */
    printf("reading client message failed\n");    
    return 0;
  }  
  if(n==0){
      break;
  }  
  printf("%.*s\n",n,buffer);  
  printf("succcccccccccccccc\n");  
}
```